# How to handle TextChanged event of a textbox in dynamically generated GridView?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have generated a `GridView` dynamically. It has columns created using Textbox Templates. Class for creating textbox template is as follows:

```
public class GridViewTextboxTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private DataControlRowType templateType;
    private string columnName;
    private string dataType;
    frmPracticalMarksEntry _PME;

    public GridViewTextboxTemplate(DataControlRowType type,
        string colname, string DataType, frmPracticalMarksEntry PME)
    {
        templateType = type;
        columnName = colname;
        dataType = DataType;
        _PME = PME;
    }
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        DataControlFieldCell hc = null;

        switch (templateType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.Header:
                // build the header for this column
                Literal lc = new Literal();
                lc.Text = columnName;
                container.Controls.Add(lc);
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                // build one row in this column
                TextBox l = new TextBox();

                // register an event handler to perform the data binding
                l.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.txt_DataBinding);
                l.TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.txt_TextChanged);

                l.AutoPostBack = true;

                container.Controls.Add(l);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void txt_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the control that raised this event
        TextBox l = (TextBox)sender;
        // get the containing row
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)l.NamingContainer;
        // get the raw data value and make it pretty
        string RawValue = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, columnName).ToString();
        l.Text = RawValue;
    }
    private void txt_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _PME.lblEr.Text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to handle a `TextChanged` event whenever a textbox value changes.
Due to this I have added the event handler `txt_TextChanged` for handling text changed event.

What happen is, if I `don't rebind the GridView again in Page_Load` event during postback then it `doesn't retain its state`.

So I need to bind it again.

Now, the `txt_TextChanged` event fires for every textbox for which the value has been changed. But it should be fired for only the textbox whose value is just changed. Hence, it returns the value of the last textbox in the grid which is not blank.